# How do you write the JS that auto fills a forms date input when you click on a div with a specific date in a html calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

Ive written simple HTML and CSS code to create a calendar and a form below it, I am completely stuck as to how to fire off a click event when a user clicks on a specific div with a date which would then auto fill the <input type="date> with what was clicked

Not too good with JS but I tried a few simple solutions which didn't work, would really appreicate some help on this

Comment: May you please add the code for the HTML i.e. calendar markup & the desired div to be clicked?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.